# DatabaseFirst MVC4 EF Code Promotion from DEV to PROD Best Practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

I was wondering where can I find best practices for Code Promotion from DEV to PROD for a MVC4 EF Web Application developed with DatabaseFirst method.

Chet

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no built-in way to do this.

You should use third-party tools like [Red Gate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) for schema and [Red Gate's Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).